# VS Code: Group files with same name and different extensions

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working in an angular2 project with vscode. Is there any way to group files with same names and different extensións as same as Visual Studio do it.

Example:

- myscript.ts
- myscript.js
- myscript.map.js

Comment: There is an issue on github for this subject: [File Nesting #6328](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6328). Please vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no but you can hide the non-ts files.

Go to Files -> Preferences -> Workspace Settings and on the right pane paste:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    
      "files.exclude": {
        // include the defaults from VS Code
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,

        // exclude .js and .js.map files, when in a TypeScript project
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
        "**/*.js.map": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want hide the files, I want that in the explorer, the js files to be child nodes of ts files.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available you can find it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_explorer-file-nesting

P.S: What is unbelievable is that in WebStorm this is not working so well. For anyone interested you can see the feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261209/Collapse-inner-nested-classes-in-the-project-view-by-default